# Make score counter from javascript display as text in html

Tags: javascript, html

(Please forgive me if this is written someplace else. I'm new to learning JS, I’ve tried many searches now and cannot find a solution still so far.)

Functionally, the program works. I’ve done console.log for `playerChoice`, `computerChoice`, `winner`, `playerScore`, and `computerScore` and everything is recognizable to identify a winner of the round. The score also does increment when I do a console.log.

*My stuck point is showing the results from the JavaScript in the HTML, incrementing the scoreboard from 0 to 1 (and on).*

I feel like this must be an easy fix, but I’ve tried everything (and searched other code examples) and cannot figure out a solution. Would greatly appreciate any help!

```js
const choices = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
const scores = document.getElementById('scores');
const restart = document.getElementById('restart-btn');

// Counter for score
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

// Play game
function playRound(e) {
    restart.style.display = 'block';
    const playerChoice = e.target.id;
    const computerChoice = computerPlay();
    const winner = getWinner(playerChoice, computerChoice);

    console.log(playerChoice, computerChoice, winner, playerScore, computerScore);
}

// Get computer choice
function computerPlay() {
    let options = [ 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]; 
}

// Get game winner
function getWinner(p, c) {
    if (p === c) {
        return 'draw';
    } else if (p === 'rock'){
        if (c === 'paper'){
            computerScore++;
            return 'computer';
        } else {
            playerScore++;
            return 'player';
        }
    } else if (p === 'paper'){
        if (c === 'scissors'){
            computerScore++;
            return 'computer';
        } else {
            playerScore++;
            return 'player';
        }
    } else if (p === 'scissors'){
        if (c === 'rock'){
            computerScore++;
            return 'computer';
        } else {
            playerScore++;
            return 'player';
        }
    }
}

// Show score
function updateScore() {
    const playerScorePara = document.getElementById("playerScore");
    const computerScorePara = document.getElementById("computerScore");

    playerScorePara.textContent = `Player: ${playerScore}`;
    computerScorePara.textContent = `Computer: ${computerScore}`;
}

// Event listeners
choices.forEach(choice => choice.addEventListener('click', playRound));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Patua+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7cbf10dcc9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</header>
    <h1 class="scoreHeading" id="scoreHeading">Score</h1>

    <div id="scores" class="score">
        <div class="playerSection">
            <p id="playerScore">Player: 0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="computerSection">
        <p id="computerScore">Computer: 0</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="choices">
        <i id="rock" class="choice far fa-hand-rock fa-10x"></i>
        <i id="paper" class="choice far fa-hand-paper fa-10x"></i>
        <i id="scissors" class="choice far fa-hand-scissors fa-10x"></i>
    </div>

    <button id="restart-btn">New Game</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to call updateScore() somewhere. Probably at the end of playRound()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, it is just that you forgot to invoke your `updateScores()` function.

I updated your addEventListener function as follows

```
choices.forEach(choice => choice.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    playRound(event);
    updateScore();
}));
```

Here is a link to your updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/o30bzpde/1/